# Animate in Y axis without moving elements below in X axis

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to achieve an effect that displays more content of a section when clicked [Just like red squares in the image]using CSS and Javascript but without disturbing nearly elements "X-axis" position and without defining statically the column amount. By now what i have done moves the block below the animated content to the right. Any suggestion or library?
Thank you very much.

Image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/un0ta6ch5xr17nk/question.png?dl=0

EDIT:

Here is the fiddle, showing what happens when clicking elementos un the left:

https://jsfiddle.net/2y2vwy0b/

And the correspondiente code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
            position: fixed;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .container{
            width: 50%;
            height: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background: #E3DBDB;
        }

        .item{
            width: 40%;
            height: 10%;
            float: left;
            margin: 1em;
            background: #7C86C0;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        /*.item:nth-child(2n+1){
            float: left;
        }

        .item:nth-child(2n){
            float: right;
        }*/

        .itemActive{
            background: #a70000;
            height: 30%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
        <div class="item">6</div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function resizeHeight( evt ) {
            evt.target.classList.toggle('itemActive');
        }

        var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
        for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
            targets[i].addEventListener("click", resizeHeight);
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the image on imgur or something?

Comment: It would help to see your current HTML and CSS code (or even a working jsfiddle of your problem). My immediate thought was simply to set `float: left` on 1,3 and 5 and `float: right` on 2, 4 and 6.

Comment: You may find CSS animations useful for this. I agree with the previous two comments It'll help if you post your current code of your site.  You can also start your search on https://css-tricks.com/ or http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about supporting older browsers, you should definitely look into [CSS3 Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It can do exactly what your image is describing using only CSS3 and possibly some media queries if you need to target different layouts for mobile devices.